# How to deploy R shinydashboard with menuSubItem not collapsed by default

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Below is some simple sample code for `shinydashboard` with various `subMenuItem` objects under a `menuItem`. By default, when the app is deployed the `subMenuItem`s are collapsed. Is there a way to set it so that they are not collapsed?

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title='Head'),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem('Tabs', tabName='tabs',
        menuSubItem('Tab 1', tabName='tab1'),
        menuSubItem('Tab 2', tabName='tab2'),
        menuSubItem('Tab 3', tabName='tab3')
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName='tab1',
        h1("Tab 1")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName='tab2',
        h1("Tab 2")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName='tab3',
        h1("Tab 3")      
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A feature that has likely been added since the OP: `startExpanded`. Set it `= TRUE` for any menu item with children you want expanded by default.

```r
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem('Tabs', tabName='tabs', startExpanded = TRUE,
        menuSubItem('Tab 1', tabName='tab1'),
        menuSubItem('Tab 2', tabName='tab2'),
        menuSubItem('Tab 3', tabName='tab3')
      )
    )
  ),
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use Javascript to change the default display style of the menu elements (by default they are `display:none` which needs to be changed to `display:block`). Add the following line after `menuItem()` (remember to add a comma also)

```
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML('$(document).ready(function() {$(".treeview-menu").css("display", "block");})')))
```

Comment: In case, there are two `menuItems`, how can I assign `display: block` to only one of them? Maybe with an id tag?